# Refactoring without configuring project

Tags: visual-studio-code, refactoring

I have c++ project in old IDE that does not support refactoring. I decided to use refactoring with Visual Studio Code. I have opened SRC folder that contains headers and cpp files. Find references and code navigation works fine, but when I tried to make refactoring I got message '`No refactorings available`'. Possible I got it since I did not configure folder to be treated as c++ project.

How to solve refactoring problem in my case in general?
Why VSCode is not able to do refactoring?